# Regex matches only once using find method in a loop

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use regex in Java to extract all results between { } and loop through them one at a time.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\{.*})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(validatePage);
while (m.find()) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(jsonObj);
}
```

This is the text I'm searching through

```
<tr><td class='warning'></td><td>test-testing-tester@2016-07-08.txt</td>
<td>TEST</td><td class='warningMessage'>[WARNING]</td><td 
class='warningMessage'>File with the revision 2016-07-08 validated 
successfully and is ready to be published. Warnings were detected. Please 
see report.</td></tr>
{"resourceUri":"test-testing-tester@2016-07-08.txt","severity":"WARNING","lineNumber":43,"column":3,"offset":701,"length":118,"message":"extension, version is missing"}
{"resourceUri":"test-testing-tester@2016-07-08.txt","severity":"WARNING","lineNumber":43,"column":3,"offset":701,"length":118,"message":"extension, release is missing"}
{"resourceUri":"test-testing-tester@2016-07-08.rxt","severity":"WARNING","lineNumber":43,"column":3,"offset":701,"length":118,"message":"extension, correction is missing"}
{"resourceUri":"test-testing-tester@2016-07-08.txt","severity":"WARNING","lineNumber":50,"column":3,"offset":825,"length":135,"message":"extension, version is missing"}
```

However m find() is looping through only once, prints the first result fine and then ends and I can't figure out why. When I run it through regex matcher it finds all the results fine. Is there something I'm missing that I need to do to match each result and loop through it?

Comment: try `(\\{.*?})`

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Code finds 4 matches. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/0EqFPI).

Comment: After reviewing code and my own answer - unable to replicate too.

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Well, I already posted proof that with text on **multiple lines**, the way it is shown in the question, there is no problem.

Comment: @Andreas seems like OP is reading it from some file or some response , collect it as a string or something which joined the strings together as one. for e.g read from file using scanner and combine it as a single string to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(\\{.*?})` to make your regex non-greedy

Remove unwanted group as

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{.*?}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(validatePage);
while (m.find()) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(m.group());
    System.out.println(jsonObj);
}
```

Comment: The 4 expected matches appear to be on different lines, and `.` doesn't match newlines, so it is *not* greedily consuming all 4 in one find.

Comment: i tested it on eclipse and the greedy version is capturing every value as single line where as the suggested fetching 4 matches

Comment: This worked perfect was driving me crazy thanks a lot!!

Comment: Then text is *not* on multiple lines, as shown in the question!